# android InputMethodManager input type

Tags: android, input, keyboard, inputmethodmanager

Is it possible to get the current input type (text or numbers) from keyboard? Or is there an event that is triggered when input type is changed? I need to set input type on a screen based on what input type was when user exited that screen. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editText.getInputType();
```

These method return the Input type of the of the EditTextBox in integer format.

you can get the of all the InputTyp by using InputType interface like this way

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT;
```

Comment: do you know why if I set editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) and whyle keyboard is up, I change from keyboard to show numbers, on editText.getInputType() I get 1 (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT) and not 2 (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER) ?

Comment: as you set as CLASS_TEXT and you enter the number it will consider as Text and you get number as CLASS_TEXT. but if you set as CLASS_NUMBER and enter number then only you can get CLASS_NUMBER.